# after installation of the git i got error of comand not found

Tags: git

I've installed git but the following command resulted in "command not found" error:

```sh
Asus@LAPTOP-OB58523N MINGW64 ~
$ git--version
bash: git--version: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The --version option is a flag to be used with the git command. You're using it as a single command with git--version. Your OS will treat this command as a whole and search for programs or resources that are registered with git--version.

This is the correct way to this command:

```
git --version
```